# How to catch Openlayers 8 GeoTIFF load error?

Tags: openlayers

Which event to catch? This code works ok if the file exists on the server, but if not (when I deliberately spoil the url), no event or catch is fired. Just AggregateError is displayed in the console.

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tile-load-events-forked-zc72gc

```
import Map from 'ol/Map.js';
import TileLayer from 'ol/layer/WebGLTile.js';
import GeoTIFFSource from 'ol/source/GeoTIFF.js';
try {
  const source = new GeoTIFFSource({
    sources: [
      {
        url:
          'https://sentinel-cogs.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sentinel-s2-l2a-cogs/36/Q/WD/2020/7/S2A_36QWD_20200701_0_L2A/TCI.tif',
      },
    ],
  });
  source.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('source error');
  });
  source.on('tileloaderror', function (e) {
    console.log('tileloaderror');
  });

  const layer = new TileLayer({source: source});
  layer.on('error', (e) => {
    console.log('layer error');
  });

  const map = new Map({
    layers: [layer],
    target: 'map',
    view: source.getView(),
  });
  map.on('error', function (e) {
    console.log('map error);
  });
} catch (e) {
  console.log('catch');
}
```

Comment: Not documented in the API, but you can find it in the source code source https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/main/src/ol/source/GeoTIFF.js#L493-L497